# Cocos2d detect touch on a specific sprite

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have this sprite that I am trying to detect if user touched it and post an NSLOG. I have read some cocos2d posts on detecting sprite touch on stackoverflow, but I got a bit confused and don't quite understand. Any help will be appreciated.I will post my sprite below.

```
chew = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"chew.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 152, 152)];
chew.position = ccp(100, 300);
[self addChild:chew];
```

Figured it out

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint( [ chew   boundingBox], location)) 
    {
        NSLog(@"touched");
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is your question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give tag values to your spirit and in touch event compare that tag value

```
chew = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"chew.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 152, 152)];
chew.position = ccp(100, 300);
chew.tag=12;
[self addChild:chew];

-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

    for (CCSprite *station in _objectList)
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(station.boundingBox, location))
        {
             if(station.tag==12)
             {
                 DLog(@"Found Your sprite");
                 return YES;
             }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: please explain what is _objectList !? in this scenario

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
- (BOOL)containsTouchLocation:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (![self visible]) return NO;

    Boolean isTouch = CGRectContainsPoint(self.rect, [self convertTouchToNodeSpaceAR:touch]);
    return isTouch;
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if ([self containsTouchLocation:touch] ) 
    {                      
        NSLog(@"Touch find");
        return YES;
    }
    else  
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Of course, in your init, you must set self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(id)event
{
    CCDirector* director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:director.openGLView];
    CGPoint locationGL = [director convertToGL:touchLocation];
    CGPoint locationInNodeSpace = [chew convertToNodeSpace:locationGL];

    CGRect bbox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 
                             chew.contentSize.width, 
                             chew.contentSize.height);

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bbox, locationInNodeSpace))
    {
        // code for when user touched chew sprite goes here ...
    }
}
```